# Return type of Query function in Android Room Database?

Tags: android-room

I have a simple question but I just can't find any documentation *anywhere*.

Suppose we have the below example, which can be found [here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Room-Guide).

```
@Dao
public interface UserDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM User WHERE userId = :id")
    public User getById(int id);
}
```

I notice the return type of the function is `User`, but what happens if there query doesn't return a result? (i.e. there is no user in the table with the specified id)

Will the function simply return `null`?

Also, if this were a Kotlin function, should the signature be the following with nullable type `User?`

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM User WHERE userId = :id")
fun getById(int id): User?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When documentation is not enough, reading sources could help.

Whatever you use (Java or Kotlin) describing Dao interface - Dao class implementation in Java (generated by Room under the hood) would be the same:

```
public User getById(int id) {
   ...
   final Cursor _cursor = DBUtil.query(__db, "SELECT * FROM User ...", false, null);
   .....
   if(_cursor.moveToFirst()) { 
       // If there is at least one record
          _result = new User(<...User's fields gotten from query...>);    
       } else {
       // If there is no record 
          _result = null;  // <---- here it is!  
       }
   return _result;
...
}
```

> Also, if this were a Kotlin function, should the signature be the following with nullable type User?

Technically you could omit `?`, but it could mislead in reading code, so better use `User?` explicitly.

Comment: Thank you! If only google had the resources to write half-decent documentation smh